# heroku app rename on facebook

Tags: facebook, heroku, rename

i've a problem on renaming just published facebook apps with heroku.
I've deleted the old working app, created a new one in heroku with a different name  and try to rename this new app with the old name of the deleted one. Testing my app with the old name (the strange standard name provided by heroku), both logged in facebook than directly on heroku domain, i observe no problems. When i rename and try to update the app on facebook, the app doesn't recognize i'm logged in, asks me to log in with the facebook button but as i try to log in an error appears in the facebook logging procedure and i'm not able to make it works. How that? i have the suspect i've to upload some links...or it could be a propagating delay time of facebbok?

thanks in advance

yes, i can seem not completely normal but i've solved just now and i think it could be a good idea to share.
When using another name for the apps it's necessary to reload in heroku the FACEBOOK_APP_ID and the FACEBOOK_SECRET
to do tha simply put yourself in the project folder and type heroku config:add FACEBOOK_APP_ID=12345 FACEBOOK_SECRET=abcde
using the right values for the app you're working on!

Comment: Glad you solved it! Please post your solution as an answer below and then mark it as accepted - thanks!